# Symfony Assert type upper

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

If I have to assert text in php:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="upper",
 *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
 * )
 */
private $one;
```

If I type text without numeric, it's ok. But if text is only numeric or numeric plus letter, I have error:
[image]

How I can assert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assert it using a regex that accepts both uppercase letters and any numbers, like this:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/\b[A-Z0-9]+\b/",
 *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid uppercase text."
 * )
 */
```

This should match any combination like: `123`, `ABC123` or `A12`

But not strings like: `a1`, `abc123`, or `ab12C`.

Comment: It's help. Thank you!